# Use a extern class on a website online, make a not found error

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I made my website for fat free, locally I have no issue, but when I put it online I can not use the class from the framework like this 
new \DB\SQL 
is throw me a Class 'DB\SQL' not found I am using namespaces.
For precision the online website is a folder inside the principal domain name, folder with its own domain name I think it's because PHP looking in the principal folder where there is not the vendor with fat-free 
sorry for the bad English

```
$this->f3 = \Base::instance();
$sql = $this->f3->get('sql');
$db = new \DB\SQL(
        $sql['dsn'],
        $sql['user'],
        $sql['password']
    );
```

Comment: If you use PSR-4 autoloading, you might need to run `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: its telling me this "Generated autoload files containing 0 classes"